# Prevent Wordpress installing plugins and themes via Admin

Tags: plugins, themes, permissions, ftp

When I initially set up WP, I had entered my FTP details in the Admin so that I could add plugins and themes directly from Admin. However, I believe this compromises the website as I  have found malware in the plugins and themes folders on many occasions.

Please can someone advise me on how I can revoke WPs FTP access? I don't want WP to be in control of adding plugins and themes and would rather do this via my FTP client.

Cheers

Comment: WordPress only has FTP access if you grant it. Just don't grant it.

Comment: Well, that is exactly the dilemma I am facing. I have changed the FTP password, but WP still seems to be able to access and add plugins and themes

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete the lines from your `wp-config.php`.

```
define('FTP_HOST', 'yourhost.com');
define('FTP_USER', 'youruser');
define('FTP_PASS', 'yourpass');
```

However, this does not automatically mean that you are secure. There are a lot of backdoors where malware could be injected, starting from the server, security-issues in your plugins, outdated software etc.

Please be sure to check for all the latest versions.

Also, if you have set your file permissions to FTP-only, you will not be able to upload media or update plugins/WordPress if you do not change them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find these lines in my wp-config file. Baffling!

Comment: Are you sure WP is using FTP..? Unless WP doesn't have write access to the WP install directory, it will generally **not** use FTP, but rather directly download files and save to disk.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent that behaviour?

Comment: Don't give permission to add themes/plugins to any user other than the primary admin.